# How to use library Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components.BodyRadiation?

Tags: openmodelica

I use the library `Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components.BodyRadiation` to study thermal radiation between 2 bodies.

Attached is my code:

```
model thermal_analysis
  
  import Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components.BodyRadiation;
  
  // Heat ports
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Interfaces.HeatPort_a port_Body1;
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Interfaces.HeatPort_b port_Body2
  
  BodyRadiation radiation(Gr=0.2);
equation
    // Connection of heat ports
    connect(port_Body1, radiation.port_a);
    connect(port_Body2, radiation.port_b);
end thermal_analysis;`
```

And I want to simulate, I have this errors:

```
[1] 11:24:15 Symbolic Error
[Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Interfaces.HeatPort: 4:3-5:75]: [Found equation without time-dependent variables: port_Body2.Q_flow = 0.0](omeditmessagesbrowser:///Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Interfaces.HeatPort?lineNumber=4)

[2] 11:24:15 Translation Error
Internal error IndexReduction.pantelidesIndexReduction failed! System is structurally singular and cannot be handled because the number of unassigned equations is larger than the number of states. Use -d=bltdump to get more information.

[3] 11:24:15 Translation Error
Internal error Transformation Module PFPlusExt index Reduction Method Pantelides failed!
```

I don't know how to fix it and make a model correctly to be able to use the library.

I try to initialise `port_Body2.Q_flow` not equal to zero and it doesn't work either. I get this error:

```
[1] 10:50:10 Symbolic Error
Too many equations, over-determined system. The model has 11 equation(s) and 10 variable(s).
```

Comment: How have you tried to address the errors stated?

Comment: I have tried initialising the port_Body2.Q_flow variable in the initial equation block and it doesn't work. The variable port_Body2 uses the library Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Interfaces.HeatPort_a, my question is this variable in the Q_flow field, can I initialize it to a value or do I have to define an equation for it?